# Anosov system: original reference requested

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

In the book

> S. Wiggins, Introduction to applied nonlinear dynamical systems and
>   chaos. Vol. 2. Springer Science $\&$ Business Media, (2003).

the author recalls a system:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=x^2, \\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=-y, \ \ \ \ \ \ (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2.
\end{cases}
$$
He attributes this system to Anosov, but the reference is:

> J. Sijbrand, Properties of center manifolds. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.
>   289, 431–469, 1985.

I'd like to know the original bibliographic source by Anosov in which it appears this system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Variable, no I don't know.

Comment: In Sijbrand paper Anosov's name is also mentioned, however the reference is made to another paper, who has no mentioning of Anosov (you can find it online,m it is freely available). I seriously doubt that there should be a reference to Anosov with respect to this, quite elementary, example.

Comment: @Artem. Thanks. I agree with you.